# Curly braces not working like they should in c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i was making a unity game, then my curly braces in my script became dumb. They all messed up and i dont know what i am doing wrong. Here is my script:
ps: i am using visual studio

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveSript : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject myObject;
    // Use this for initialization
    private Vector3 direction = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    // Update is called once per frame
    private float speed = 40f;
    void Start() { // error here? --> "} expected"

        private Camera cam = Camera.main;
        private float height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
        private float width = height * cam.aspect;
    } // i close it here, but it closes the mono beh. class instead?

    void Update () {
        int y = 0;
        int x = 0;
        if (Input.GetKey("up"))
        {
            y = 1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("down"))
        {
            y = -1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("right"))
        {
            x = 1;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("left"))
        {
            x = -1;
        }
        direction = new Vector3(x, y, 0);
        myObject.transform.position += direction.normalized*speed*Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

What am i doing wrong? Thanks for advance!

Comment: Is any error occurring? Do you mean that the indentation is messing up?

Comment: @fhcimolin i am doing it in visual studio, at the "start() {" it says "} expected", but i closed it later?

Comment: You're declaring global variables in an instance method, check your `start` method, `private` can't be used there.

Comment: The `private` keyword doesn't belong (or make sense) on locally declared variables within a method.  Try focusing less on calling the compiler insulting names and focus more on the syntax and structure of your code.  I assure you, you're not going to hurt the compiler's feelings or get it to change its mind.

Comment: Ahhh, ok thanks. I am pretty new to c# so i forgot what private does, but used it lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not define accessibility in local variables defined inside a method. It should either be

```
private void Start() 
{
    var cam = Camera.main;
    var height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
    var width = height * cam.aspect;

    // Makes only sense if you now use the width
    // and/or other values for something
}
```

Or define them at class level (e.g. to access them also in other methods later) like

```
private Camera cam;
private float height;
private float width;

private void Start() 
{
    cam = Camera.main;
    height = 2f * cam.orthographicSize;
    width = height * cam.aspect;
}
```